# C# Winform context menu strip delete function

Tags: c#, contextmenustrip

I want to create a delete function in context menu strip something like this:
[image]

I have created the code but it is not functioning. am I wrong or is there any other method to do this?

```
private void deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Int32 rowToDelete = dataGridView1.Rows.GetFirstRow(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(rowToDelete);
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
    }
```

Comment: What does the debugger tell you about the value of rowToDelete? Did you put a breakpoint into the function to see what is going on?

Comment: @JohannBlais it say Row index provided is out of range.any idea?